Selenium не долистывает google-фото до конца
У меня есть код
def google(file):
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://google.com/")

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "nDcEnd").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cB9M7').send_keys('https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/waves-splashing-against-roker-lighthouse-600w-1872298606.jpg')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "Qwbd3").click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ICt2Q").click()
time.sleep(5)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(2)

a = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "rqhI4d")
a = a.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "button")
while a:
    a.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") 
    time.sleep(2)
    a = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "rqhI4d")
    a = a.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "button")
    print('oks')
print('ok')

time.sleep(100000)

driver.close()

В переменной a находится кнопка, которая открывает дополнительные результаты поиска. Но при a.click() происходит ошибка
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-Bz112c-M1Soyc VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe LQeN7 m9ViNc W72mFf xTRO1d"> is not clickable at point (560,823) because another element <div class="ekSIQ"> obscures it

Также я вижу, что метод window.scrollTo не долистывает страницу до конца и кнопку не видно. Из-за этого видимо и происходит проблема. Как это исправить?
